# getting HTTP Status 404 - 502.shtml The requested resource is not available.while uploading a file

Tags: java, php, tomcat, servlets, cpanel

I'm getting the above error while using servlet I've written. the war file is set on Tomcat ver 7.0.39 installed on cPanel. the servlet compiled and tested on local machine no problem. I've learnet that there is a problem that has something to do with the cPanel/PHP config.  I tried to play with the cPanel configuration but no luck
I feel that it has nothing to do with the java code but I'll put the fileUploadServlet anyhow

EDIT: I was able to upload a very small-sized file so it has something to do with file size \ long procssing time

```
package servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import convertor.TextAnalayzer;

import exception.ZoharException;

import beans.ParashaBean;
import beans.UserBean;

import jdbcHandler.JDBCZhoarHandler;

import util.ParashaName;
import util.XmlUrelParaser;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/upload" }, loadOnStartup = 1)
@MultipartConfig
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8626646959046203428L;
    private JDBCZhoarHandler appHandler = new JDBCZhoarHandler();
    public static final String ERROR_PARAMETER = "error";
    public static final String COMMAND_PARAMETER = "command";
    public static final String USER_ATTRIBUTE = "user";
    public static final String HANDLER_ATTRIBUTE = "handler";

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        try {
            getServletConfig().getServletContext().setAttribute("list",
                    appHandler.viewParashot());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String command = request.getParameter(COMMAND_PARAMETER);
        String nextPage = "/login.jsp";
        if ("convert".equals(command)) {
            nextPage = this.upload(request, response);
        } else if ("login".equals(command)) {
            nextPage = this.login(request, response);
        } else {
        }// do nothing!!

        this.getServletConfig().getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(nextPage).forward(request, response);
    }

    private String login(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        String name = request.getParameter("userName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        JDBCZhoarHandler handler = new JDBCZhoarHandler();
        try {
            UserBean user = handler.getUser(name, password);
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute(HANDLER_ATTRIBUTE, handler);
            session.setAttribute(USER_ATTRIBUTE, user.getId());
            return "/uploadFile.jsp";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            request.setAttribute(ERROR_PARAMETER, e.getMessage());
            return "/login.jsp";
        }

    }

    private String upload(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        // view artifacts
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        ParashaName parashaName = new ParashaName();
        JDBCZhoarHandler handler = (JDBCZhoarHandler) session
                .getAttribute(HANDLER_ATTRIBUTE);
        List<ParashaBean> list = null;
        try {
            list = handler.viewParashot();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            request.setAttribute(ERROR_PARAMETER, e1.getMessage());
        }
        session.setAttribute("list", list);

        // Processing file
        if ("convert".equals(request.getParameter("command"))) {

            OutputStream out = null;
            InputStream filecontent = null;

            try {
                // Create path components to save the file
                XmlUrelParaser xml = new XmlUrelParaser();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd-MM-yy_HH-mm-ss");
                final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
                if (filePart.getSize() == 0) {
                    throw new ZoharException("you must upload a file first");
                }
                final String fileName = xml.getUR("incomingFilesDir")
                        + session.getAttribute(USER_ATTRIBUTE)
                        + parashaName.convert(Integer.parseInt(request
                                .getParameter("parasha")))
                        + format.format(new Date()) + ".docx";

                out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
                filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

                int read = 0;
                final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                TextAnalayzer ta = new TextAnalayzer();
                Integer ID = (Integer)session.getAttribute("user");
                ta.analayze(fileName,
                        Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("parasha")),
                        Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("orginal")),
                        ID);
                request.setAttribute(ERROR_PARAMETER, "Upload complete");
                return "/uploadFile.jsp";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                request.setAttribute(ERROR_PARAMETER, e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                    if (filecontent != null) {
                        filecontent.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    request.setAttribute(ERROR_PARAMETER, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return "/login.jsp";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a resault of memory lack. Better memory-managing code solved the problem.